# Struggling with gd:organization, specifically gd:orgName? and gd:orgTitle?

Tags: php

Having difficulty pushing and pulling Contact data using Google Contacts API, specifically as it relates to OrgName and OrgTitle.

Here is example of what i sent:

```
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'
                                xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'
                                xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008'>
                                <atom:category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>

                                <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/devteam@zeppidy.com/base/795eba52880dd744</id>



                              <gd:name>
                                 <gd:givenName>Amy</gd:givenName>
                                 <gd:familyName>Larsson</gd:familyName>
                                 <gd:fullName>Amy Larsson</gd:fullName>
                              </gd:name>
                              <atom:content type='text'></atom:content>
                                <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work' address='email'/>
                                <gd:phoneNumber rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home'>0</gd:phoneNumber>
                                <gd:structuredPostalAddress rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work'>
                                <gd:city>Lake Oswego</gd:city>


                                <gd:formattedAddress>
                                  330 Oak Lake Oswego,  - State -  
                                </gd:formattedAddress>
                              </gd:structuredPostalAddress>
                                <gd:organization label='Work' primary='true'/>
                            <gd:orgName>test c</gd:orgName>
                            <gd:orgTitle>test tt3</gd:orgTitle>                            
                        </gd:organization>
                             <gContact:groupMembershipInfo deleted='false' href='http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/groups/devteam@zeppidy.com/base/1e8391f408b028e1'/>

                            </atom:entry>
```

When i remove the following organization info, everything works fine:

```
<gd:organization label='Work' primary='true'/>
<gd:orgName>test c</gd:orgName>
<gd:orgTitle>test tt3</gd:orgTitle>                            
</gd:organization>
```

Any recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: What is the response / error you get?

Comment: The element type &quot;atom:entry&quot; must be terminated by the matching end-tag &quot;&lt;/atom:entry&gt;&quot;.

Answer (score 0):

```
<gd:organization label='Work' primary='true'/>
```

This tag is closed itself. No need for `</gd:organization>` at the end. In your case you probably want to remove `/` at the first line.